# Concurrent transaction issue in activiti framework we have fixed but need some feedback

Tags: jdeveloper, activiti, bpmn

We have used Activiti framework version 5.15 and we are getting concurrent modification issue for job execution.

also mentioned error stack trace

```
2018-09-19 16:13:46,083 ERROR [org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable] (pool-4-thread-30) exception during job execution: ProcessInstance[34391064] was updated by another transaction concurrently: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiOptimisticLockingException: ProcessInstance[34391064] was updated by another transaction concurrently
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.flushUpdates(DbSqlSession.java:622)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.flush(DbSqlSession.java:503)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.flushSessions(CommandContext.java:182)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.close(CommandContext.java:128)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:66)
at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.run(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:52)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We have fix this issue with hazelcast locking mechanisum into processInstanceId because it is unique during hole workflow execution.

We have taken hazelcast lock when activiti begin transaction(**in ExecuteJobCommand.java before  job.execute(commandContext); **) for executing service task, And release this lock when activiti commit  transaction (for service task) in CommandContext.java after  transactionContext.commit();

Using this mechanisum we had solve issue(concurrent modification exception).

I need some suggestion that it will create any problem in production for job execution? 
and suggest that if anyone have another solution for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to see this with multiple Activiti 5 engines running and async execution. This is part of the design of the Activiti 5 job executor - if you have multiple of them running then each will try to run the job and the first to get there wins. You can see this as a benign exception as what happens in the losing executions will not be committed (unless you do something in custom code in that execution which can't be rolled back like an http call). See https://community.alfresco.com/thread/221722-activitioptimisticlockingexception-on-even-the-simplest-process The most popular way to avoid seeing this tends to be to disable the job executor on all but one of the engines so that only that one is processing async jobs (effectively it is a 'leader').

Comment: Can anyone describe how to check if you have more than one Activiti Engine running?

Based on the forum link that was shared, should I be using

`spring.activiti.async-executor-activate=true`

instead of 

`spring.activiti.job-executor-activate=true`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with internals of Activiti but Hazelcast distributed locks work very well. I think the main problem you might have would be performance related. As with any locked/synchronized code block, you are serializing your process there which could be an issue as you scale up. Also you need to be very sure that you always release the lock when a process leaves the code block, especially on exceptions. You will get a deadlock if you don't.